# AllowAutoRedirect Functionality when using sockets

Tags: c#, http, sockets

I'm aware that HttpWebRequest has a parameter available to set URL redirection to false (request.AllowAutoRedirect = False;).

How is this done when using a Socket connection directly?

I don't have any code to show since I'm just starting down the road of development on a project.

Unfortunately, I need to stick to using Socket connections and cannot use HttpWebRequest, WebClient or HTTPClient. :(

Comment: Why can't you use them? Are you not connecting to an HTTP service? If not, what protocol are you using?

Comment: I'm building a video streaming application and the other options are too slow for the connection. When using sockets, the app flies, any other type there is lag. Is there a parameter to set this when using sockets? HTTPWebRequest is using sockets, so it must be possible, does anyone know what the code looks like or what parameter to use?

Comment: Redirection is an application protocol (e.g. HTTP) matter. You use sockets to directly access the transport protocol (TCP), on top of which you program the application protocol. If you receive a response that says to go somewhere else, you close the socket, open a new socket to the other host, and retry there. HTTP redirects can be to a resource on the same host, so those clients would likely keep the socket open.

Comment: Thank you for the details madreflection! Strange, I just did some testing and when I send a specific URL via HTTPWebRequest (with AllowAutoRedirect set to false), I get a 302 response back and the redirected URL shown under the location header. When I do the same on the socket connection, I get a timeout and I get a 408 timeout response. you may have nailed it, the redirection is to another host. Understood, I need to create another socket to this new host! Perfect, thank you folks!! :)

Comment: 408 is a "request timeout", which means you haven't sent a complete request and the server is tired of waiting. You're not getting a redirect *at all*. You should go back to using one of the other types. They're not inherently slow; I posit that you weren't using them correctly for efficient communication. Show some code using one of the provided web client types and get help figuring out what you need to fix there.

Comment: Yup, that was it! :)  The request wasn't complete! Seeing the redirection now! All is good, thank your for your excellent troubleshooting madreflection. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a socket redirection.

An HTTP redirection is where you connect to the server specified, send your HTTP request, and server sends a HTTP response which tells you to go to a different URL instead. So then you go that URL instead.

It looks like this:

```
*** socket opened to example.com

*** client sends this part:
GET /some/address HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

*** server sends this part:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://other.example.com/some_place?really=yes

*** socket closed to example.com
```

if you have auto-redirect disabled, this is the response your program gets. Otherwise, the HTTP library keeps going:

```
*** socket opened to other.example.com

*** client sends this part:
GET /some_place?really=yes HTTP/1.1
Host: other.example.com

*** server sends this part:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 11

hello world

*** socket closed to other.example.com
```

If you are just using sockets you will be doing this yourself to begin with.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!